# Puppet 2.7: Calling puppet apply init.pp does nothing - why?

Tags: manifest, apply, puppet

Directory and file layout as follows:

```
app_test/
app_test/manifests
app_test/manifests/init.pp
app_test/manifests/test.pp
```

Contents of `init.pp`:

```
class app_test {
    include app_test::test
}
```

Contents of `test.pp`:

```
class app_test::test {
    exec { 'hello world':
        command => "/bin/echo Hello World >> /tmp/are-you-there.txt"
    }
}
```

Puppet `v2.7.11` is installed.

```
$ puppet apply init.pp 
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds
```

Could someone please indicate why this doesn't generate the file `/tmp/are-you-there-txt`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try :

```
 puppet apply -e 'include app_test::test'
```

or for a dry run

```
 puppet apply -e 'include app_test::test' --noop
```

For more puppet apply, see manual page : http://docs.puppetlabs.com/man/apply.html

Answer (score 11):

You are only defining classes, not declaring them.

Create a file modules/[module_name]/tests/init.pp:

Contents:

```
include app_test
```

Test your class then with:

```
puppet apply tests/init.pp
```

That should do the trick!

Kind regards,

Ger Apeldoorn